# How to read gradle file properties from Android app programatically

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

The build.gradle file has the following section. How to read the **android.defaultConfig.versionCode** from the android app **MainActivity**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gatta.e.gatta"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to read the Gradle file to obtain the version code. Here is the direct way from within an activity:

```
private PackageInfo getPackageInfo() {
    PackageInfo pi;
    try {
        pi = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                         this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO: handle this
        Log.e("yourMessage", e);
    }
    return pi;
}
```

And use  this in your `onCreate(...)` method for example to obtain the version code:

```
String versionCode = "" + getPackageInfo().versionCode;
```

More info on the `PackageInfo` class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html). And a quick description of the class:

> Overall information about the contents of a package. This corresponds to all of the information collected from AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: In addition, I don't even think it is possible to  read the gradle files with an built-in API, because not all IDEs seems to use Gradle to build the APKs, so it wouldn't be worth implementing it.

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12: Correct. Moreover, it seems like the _build.gradle_ isn't even included in the APK when you build using Android Studio, which makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't read any property in the build.gradle file but there is an API to get the application version code and version name.

That's the utility class that I always use.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;

/**
 * Utility class used in getting application version code and version name.
 */
public class AppUtils {

        /**
         * @return Application's version code from the PackageManager.
         */
        public static int getAppVersionCode(Context context) {
                try {
                        PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                                        .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0); 
                        return packageInfo.versionCode;
                } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                        // should never happen
                        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e); 
                }
        }

        /**
         * @return Application's version name from the PackageManager.
         */
        public static String getAppVersionName(Context context) {
                try {
                        PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                                        .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0); 
                        return packageInfo.versionName;
                } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                        // should never happen
                        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e); 
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Above properties are build config specific. You can refer them in your java file as BuildConfig.propertyName since all the build config variables are translated to static resource in file BuildConfig.java automatically.
 e.g. applicationId can be used as

```
    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
```

in your case you can refer versionCode as :

```
    BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
```

if you want to have custom BuildConfig you can also do so as follows:
 in your build.gradle default config/ flavor section use :

```
   buildConfigField "variable type", "variable name", new Type(var name)
```

e.g.

```
   multiDexEnabled false
   buildConfigField "Boolean", "MY_FIELD", new Boolean(multiDexEnabled).toString
```

I hope it helps.